# How to implement close Popup for Multipolygon?

Tags: leaflet, popup, multipart

I am closing the popup for geoJson (layer.closePopup()) to make a modal to appear. The function works fine for regular geometry but fails for Multipolygon. I get the error - ClosePopup is not a defined function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2992) that can be solved by using `group.invoke('closePopup')` instead of `group.closePopup()`, see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c24u2b5o/